# Why the UGUI is blurry on android?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am using UGUI to make a UI, but I found it very blurry on android, not so clear compare to the original png.

Is there some reason?

Someone said that change the "Texture Type" to "Advance", cancel the "generate mip maps" and change the "Filter Mode" to "Point" would make it more clear. But it seems not work to me.

Are there some solutions?

Comment: the suggestion is right on the money, make sure that you deselected mip maps and then push apply, otherwise your change won't be persistent. Changing the Filter Mode to Point may yield unwanted results, like increase sharpness, so you may try to set it to Bilinear if that happens

Comment: Also check your Quality Settings as they can be different on a per platform basis.